# How to add to an Immutable map : Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a ResultSet object returned from Hive using JDBC.

I am trying to store the values in a resultset in a Scala Immutable Map.

How can i add there values to an Immutable map as i am iterating the resultset using while loop

```
val m : Map[String, String] = null

while ( resultSet.next() ) {
        val col = resultSet.getString("col_name")
        val data = resultSet.getString("data_type")

      m += (col -> data) // This Gives Reassignment error
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I propose :

```
Iterator.continually{
    val col = resultSet.getString("col_name")
    val data = resultSet.getString("data_type")
    col->data
  }.takeWhile( _ => resultSet.next()).toMap
```

Instead of thinking "let's init an empty collection and fill it" which is imho the mutable way to think, this proposition rather think in terms of "let's declare how to build a collection with those elements in it and be done" :-)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use `scala.collection.Iterator[A]` so that you can create immutable map out of your java `resultSet`.

```
val myMap : Map[String, String] = new Iterator[(String, String)] {

  override def hasNext = resultSet.next()

  override def next() = {
    val col = resultSet.getString("col_name")
    val data = resultSet.getString("data_type")

    col -> data
  }

}.toMap
```

Otherwise you have to use mutable `scala.collection.mutable.Map`.